# How can I mirror my samsung phone screen on my Tv

Tags: applications, screen-sharing

I have a upnp enable TV on which [ImediaShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bianor.ams&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLmJpYW5vci5hbXMiXQ..) seems to work fine. But does anyone know how to mirror my phone screen on the TV

Comment: uPnP usually does no screen sharing. Do both your devices (TV and Android) feature a HDMI port? That's the way it is mostly done.